# different behavior when mixing DLLs from different MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, windows-10

I know that mixing DLLs from different MSVC is bad and should be avoided.
Here I would like to know the reason of their different behavior.

Background:

Having 3rd party library shipped with (XXX.dll, XXX.lib and XXX.h)
I use it in my application with implicit linking.
They are all x64.

- my application is built with **MSVC 2015**.
- The 3rd party XXX.dll is apparently built with **MSVC 2008** and

  - Unfortunately there is pointer involved in function calls from XXX.dll
  - e.g. `int __stdcall func1(const char * arg);` to have string as argument
  - e.g. `int __stdcall func2(char * arg);` to get string filled by DLL

Different Setup:

**On Windows 7 (x64)**

It works just fine.

**On Windows 10 (x64)**

I get access violation exception from XXX.dll due to reading invalid memory location. (i.e. calling `int __stdcall func1(const char * arg);`)

```
Exception thrown at 0x000001EF05A2BBB9 (XXX.dll) in Application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000074A3A68.
```

(it sounds reasonable when there are two CRTs/Heaps and pointer transfer will not work.)

Question:

Why it works on Windows 7?

I use the same MSVC2015 tool-chain and would expect the same behavior.
Or is there something OS related?

Thanks.

Comment: If dll is exposing C interface and does not perform resource ownership transfer then it should work perfectly fine even if build with different version of compiler or completely different compiler. Simply reading `arg` should not cause any problems. Have you inspected the call stack to figure out what is the failure point?

Comment: Neither of those should be a problem *unless* `func2` eventually frees the non-const string pointer you gave it *and* said-same pointer did not originate from some *other* call to the library. Then you're in trouble. Unrelated, find the author and slap him upside the head for taking a "write-to-my-buffer" pointer without an argument specifying sizing constraints. That's just a recipe for disaster. There's a reason `gets` was pulled from the standard library.

Comment: May be, it's even simpler (and has nothing to do with DLLs and mixed MSVC runtimes): There is a call of `func1()` with success on Windows 7 which failed on Windows 10 (for any reason). Somebody forgot to check the success of `func1()`, and thus, consecutive processing of return value crashs in the latter case. (Sorry, if I mixed `func1()` and `func2()` but I guess you got my point.)

Comment: thx.  all make sense. I am trying to dig deeper...  and will update soon

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the original question is not really valid.
When I look at stack trace. The exception is actually thrown by a (msvcr90.dll) thread from the XXX.DLL.

Here is the question with more detail

[Debug 3rd party DLL causing access violation after upgrading to Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51747719/debug-3rd-party-dll-causing-access-violation-after-upgrading-to-windows-10)