# Debug 3rd party DLL causing access violation after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, windows-10, reverse-engineering

> I know that mixing DLLs from different MSVC is bad and should be
>   avoided...

I have a 3rd party DLL (XXX.dll, XXX.lib, XXX.h) which is implicitly linked in my application.

The original setup is:

- My application (built with VS **2015**)
- XXX.dll (built with VS **2008**)
- **x64**
- Windows 7

And it worked!

However moving to **Windows 10**:
(My application is re-built with VS 2015 and still with XXX.dll)

Now the application keeps crash with access violation
`Exception thrown at 0x000001EF05A2BBB9 (XXX.dll) in Application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000074A3A68.`

Here is the call stack:

```
XXX.dll!000002a7eeb6bbb9()   
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()     
user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()   
mfc90u.dll!AfxInternalPumpMessage()  
mfc90u.dll!CWinThread::Run()     
mfc90u.dll!_AfxThreadEntry(pParam=0x000000d5452fd890)   
msvcr90.dll!_callthreadstartex()     
msvcr90.dll!_threadstartex(ptd=0x0000000000000000)   
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()   
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
```

As usual, "3rd party" support is very unhelpful...

What could cause this problem suddenly on Win 10?
What kind of mistake could XXX.dll!000002a7eeb6bbb9() make to mess up memory?

I was thinking about the problem mixing different CRT and it is the orignal question: 
[different behavior when mixing DLLs from different MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741014/different-behavior-when-mixing-dlls-from-different-msvc)

Comment: It's undefined behavior to use a dll from vs 2008 with your compiler. That is unless the dll isolates the heap an does not use the standard library in it's interface.

Comment: What do you mean by "after the upgrade to Win10?" Did you just copy / paste the compiled binaries to Win10, or did you compile your application with a different version of VS?

Comment: MS does not support DLLs/EXEs from different version of VS.  Unless the interface is pure `C` and memory management is confined to each DLL

Comment: It may have worked with a different OS, UB unfortunately sometimes appears to work.

Comment: I update the original post

Comment: @drescherjm thx for advice...  I just want to collect possible cause and give feedback to unhelpful 3rd party...  heap isolation and avoid std lib are goold points.